# PHP dynamic schedule Email sending out

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

My application is running in Wordpress as a plugin. The application has many projects with a value of email frenquency, which will be saved on the database and the value will be: weekly, daily and every Tuesday and Thursday.

Now, I'm going to set up a email scheduler that the scheduled emails will be sent to the projects participants weekly, daily or twice a week depends on the frenquency.

My question is how can I set the email scheduler first. As Wordpress cron is based on the page loading, whereas my purpse is not relied on any page load, so I cannot use the Wordpress cron system. I've seen some articles suggest to use server cron itself. Can anyone give me a brief based on my requirements? Is it possible I can get a dynamic value from database using in the cron script? Plus, I didn't use Laravel for this one. I know Laravel has the task scheduling functionality.

The second quesiton is if I use corn with php script, can I set up the schedule to every Tuesday and Thursday?

Thirdly, I also see some libraries like SendGrid which has a schedule functionality, should I use it or keep on Cron?

Comment: You could use WP Cron and have the crontab load the home page or you could directly call a script in your plugin. So long as the script loads the wp-load.php file, it'll have full database access. You may however want to secure the script with a .htaccess file to prevent it being accessed directly outside of the server.

Comment: The Wordpress official website says if there is no page loaded, the scheduled task will not run and then delay. My scenario is if no one visit any page, the scheduled tasks can still work. That's why I feel the WP Cron is not suitable for me.

Comment: That is why I was saying one option is to have the server crontab load the WP page at whatever frequency you want it called.

Answer (score 0):

1. Code PHP script(s) to handle sending emails according to data retrieved from DB.

Then create Cron to call certain PHP script(s) which runs on daily basis if customers can choose which day they prefer to get the emails.

2. Yes.
3. Cron is more secure, stable and independant.